# NLog not working in VS 2017 .NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nlog, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm attempting to load NLog into my .NET core web app in VS 2017 following [this](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(project.json)) tutorial.  This tutorial is using a project.json file whereas my VS 2017 project is using a csproj file.

The first thing I did was add the `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` NuGet package to my web project.

Then, in my Startup.cs file, I added the following to the top of my `Startup()` method:

```
env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
```

Next, in my `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)` method, I added the following to the top:

```
//add NLog to ASP.NET Core
loggerFactory.AddNLog();

//add NLog.Web
app.AddNLogWeb();
```

I added a nlog.config file to the root of my web app and defined is the same as in the linked tutorial.

Lastly, I injected a `ILogger<MyController> logger` dependency into a Web API controller and attempt to call LogInformation().  I do not get any errors.  It just doesn't log anything to my temp directory.

Comment: What temp directory?

Comment: @mason The one defined in the nlog.config in the tutorial (c:\temp\).

Comment: There is a working example in github: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/tree/master/examples/aspnet-core-example

Comment: @Julian I just made my project match the example exactly and still nothing. I made the Startup.cs match and also had to import NLog.Extensions.Logging. Curiously the example doesn't reference nlog.config.

Comment: Also copied over the NLog.xsd file.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest NLog (5.0 beta6). You could check the internal log, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: @Julian I'm using NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.3.1 and NLog.Extensions.Logging 1.0.0-rtm-beta4.  I'm already setup for internal logging...

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: @Julian Yes, Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Is the example also not working on your machine?

Comment: @Julian The example works fine, but my solution does not, even after I configure it the same as the example...

Answer (score 0):

Try to move configuration to `App.config` See

```
 NLog.Extensions.Logging-master\examples\net-fullframework-example\src\net-
 app-using-nlog\App.config as example
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [same tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2) and had the same issue as you!

1. Reboot your machine
2. Turn on the NLog setting `throwExceptions="true"` as recommended [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting).  This will allow NLog itself to report its own exceptions.
3. Make sure NLog.config is being copied to the output folder by setting the properties on the file.[image]
4. When running locally check your solution folder and sub-folder, 
   *bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1*.  NLog.config must be there when running in Debug mode.
5. Even with **Copy always**, my file was not being copied b/c visual studio was confused between NLog.config and nlog.config.  The reboot helped that for some reason - also I committed my changes in git.
6. `connectionStringName` is not supported on DatabaseTarget (For .NET 2.1).  Use `connectionString` instead.  See [this github issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/61) for more details.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43852725/1804678) for the fix.

Comment: Please never turn on `throwExceptions="true"`. It should not be recommended anywhere. It is same of having a loaded shotgun pointing at your foot. Instead use the NLog InternalLogger if you want to perform troubleshooting.

Comment: `throwExceptions="true"` is recommended by the NLog troubleshooting document.  But you are right, you do not want it turned on in a production environment.

Comment: Guess the Wiki should be updated to promote `throwConfigExceptions="true"` and using the InternalLogger. Keeping the forbidden setting as last resort.